# css select with changing numbering

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to apply the same css to the following selectors :

```
button#ff_elem162_calendarButton.bfCalendar
button#ff_elem164_calendarButton.bfCalendar
```

I know how to select the first part with

```
[id^="#ff_elem"]
```

but I also need to add this part

```
_calendarButton.bfCalendar
```

to select the good ones.

Do someone know how to achieve this.

Would appreciate your expertise.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use selector like this:

```
button[id^="ff_elem"][id$="_calendarButton"]
```

- `[id^="ff_elem"]` will select all elements where `id` starts with `ff_elem`.
- `[id$="_calendarButton"]` will select all elements where `id` ends with `_calendarButton`

```css
button[id^="ff_elem"][id$="_calendarButton"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="ff_elem162_calendarButton" class="bfCalendar">btn1</button>
<button id="ff_elem164_calendarButton" class="bfCalendar">btn2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad works, glad to know now how to do. Cheers, Marc